# Using Axios for API call, trying to grab 9 songs at a time out of 100 limit on Napster API

Tags: javascript, axios

I am currently using Axios to get song and image data from Napster API. In my JavaScript, I have a click event listener that is creating a div for each song and artist image in the playlist that generates when you press a submit button. I have currently set the limit in the API URL to 9 songs to be displayed out of the 100+ songs in the particular playlist. I was wondering if there was a way I could start with just 9 songs being displayed on the page, but when another button was pressed I could grab 9 more songs to be appended to the 9 existing songs.

```
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", function (event) {


    const napsterSongURL = "https://api.napster.com/v2.1/playlists/pp.188152066/tracks?apikey=" + napsterKey + "&limit=9";
    console.log(napsterSongURL);


    axios.get(napsterSongURL).then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);


        let napsterSongData = response.data.tracks;


        for (i = 0; i < napsterSongData.length; i++) {
            let myUrl = napsterSongData[i].previewURL;
            let artistID = napsterSongData[i].artistId;
            let artistImageURL = "https://api.napster.com/imageserver/v2/artists/" + artistID +
                "/images/300x300.jpg?apikey=" + napsterKey + "&limit=9";
            let artistImage = "<img id='artistImage' src=' " + artistImageURL + "'/>";


            let songDiv = document.createElement("div");
            songDiv.classList.add("songDisplay");


            let html = artistImage + "<audio controls><source class='audioSource' src=" + myUrl + "></audio>";
            songDiv.innerHTML += html;

            document.getElementById("napsterDiv").append(songDiv);
        }

    })
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the offset for paging.  Haven't tested but I think something like this would work:

```
let perPage = 9;
let offset = 0;
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", function (event) {


    const napsterSongURL = "https://api.napster.com/v2.1/playlists/pp.188152066/tracks?apikey=" + napsterKey + "&limit=" + perPage + "&offset=" + offset;


    axios.get(napsterSongURL).then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);


        let napsterSongData = response.data.tracks;

        offset += napsterSongData.length;
        for (i = 0; i < napsterSongData.length; i++) {
            let myUrl = napsterSongData[i].previewURL;
            let artistID = napsterSongData[i].artistId;
            let artistImageURL = "https://api.napster.com/imageserver/v2/artists/" + artistID +
                "/images/300x300.jpg?apikey=" + napsterKey + "&limit=9";
            let artistImage = "<img id='artistImage' src=' " + artistImageURL + "'/>";


            let songDiv = document.createElement("div");
            songDiv.classList.add("songDisplay");


            let html = artistImage + "<audio controls><source class='audioSource' src=" + myUrl + "></audio>";
            songDiv.innerHTML += html;

            document.getElementById("napsterDiv").append(songDiv);

        }

    })

})
```

Comment: It seems that setting the offset in the URL only skips the first songs that are in the array by what you set that number to, but still populates the same songs every time. I'm hoping to add 9 new songs each time you hit the button.

Comment: Ignore previous comment, this worked perfectly!  I missed where you gave offset the value of += napsterSongData. When I added that it worked perfectly. Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this would work:

```
const napsterSongURL = 

"https://api.napster.com/v2.1/playlists/pp.188152066/tracks?apikey=" + napsterKey + "&limit=9";
console.log(napsterSongURL);

var maxIdx = 9;

axios.get(napsterSongURL).then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);


    let napsterSongData = response.data.tracks;


    for (i = 0; i < napsterSongData.length && i < maxIdx; i++) {
        let myUrl = napsterSongData[i].previewURL;
        let artistID = napsterSongData[i].artistId;
        let artistImageURL = "https://api.napster.com/imageserver/v2/artists/" + artistID +
            "/images/300x300.jpg?apikey=" + napsterKey + "&limit=9";
        let artistImage = "<img id='artistImage' src=' " + artistImageURL + "'/>";


        let songDiv = document.createElement("div");
        songDiv.classList.add("songDisplay");


        let html = artistImage + "<audio controls><source class='audioSource' src=" + myUrl + "></audio>";
        songDiv.innerHTML += html;

        document.getElementById("napsterDiv").append(songDiv);
    }

})
```

Each time the user would press the button, you only have to increase maxIdx by 9:

```
maxIdx += 9
```

Comment: What Id are you referring to with Idx?

Comment: I ment to write maxIdx, just fixed it